# ReactJS Dropdown menu, close other menus before opening current

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have made some dropdown menus:

```
export default class DropdownMenu extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.state = {
            menuOpen: false,
            highlight: false,
            count: this.props.count | 0
        }
        this.showDropdown = this.showDropdown.bind(this);
    }

    componentDidMount() {

    }

    showDropdown() {
            this.setState({
                menuOpen: !this.state.menuOpen
            });
    }

    render() {
        return <div className="dropdown__menu" onClick={this.showDropdown}>
            {this.props.text} {this.state.count > 0 ? <b>{this.state.count}</b> : ''}
            <div className="dropdown__content" style={this.state.menuOpen ? {'display': 'block'} : {'display': 'none'}}>
                {this.props.children}
            </div>
        </div>
    }
}
```

The issue is that you can open all of them and leave them open until you click on them again to close them. How do I make it so that any other menu that is open gets closed if another is opened?

---

Here is where they are implemented:

```
render() {
        ...
                <div className="filter_container">
                    <DropdownMenu text="New" count={127} disabled/>
                    <DropdownMenu text="Only show">
                        <li>New</li>
                        <li>Old</li>
                    </DropdownMenu>
                    <DropdownMenu text="Other">
                        <li>one</li>
                        <li>two</li>
                    </DropdownMenu>
                    <DropdownMenu text="Sort by">
                        <li>Name</li>
                        <li>Age</li>
                        <li>Value</li>
                    </DropdownMenu>
                </div>
            </div>
...
```

Comment: Do you run a map to render a list of DropdownMenus..Can you show the code for that component ?

Comment: @anuragb26 Please see my edit.

Comment: @imperium2335 did you have a chance to see the solutions? Do you find any of them useful?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since react got one way data flow you need to do this in parent component

```
import React from 'react'

class DropdownParent extends React.Component {

  state = {
    openedDropdown: null,
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <Dropdown
          name="dropdown1"
          isOpen={this.state.openedDropdown === 1}
          onClick={() => this.setState({ openedDropdown: 1 })}
          onClose={() => this.setState({ openedDropdown: null })}
        />
        <Dropdown
          name="dropdown2"
          isOpen={this.state.openedDropdown === 2}
          onClick={() => this.setState({ openedDropdown: 2 })}
          onClose={() => this.setState({ openedDropdown: null })}
        />
      </React.Fragment>
    )
  }
}
```

and then you need Dropdown to be based on **props.isOpen**, not on your **state.menuOpen** and use **props.onClick** / **props.onClose** instead of **this.showDropdown**

Alternatively you can base on mouse (like **onMouseDown** **onMouseEnter**...) or focus (**onFocus** **onBlur**) events but this is hard to get mobile friendly and won't ensure you about "only one dropdown at the same moment".
more info: https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html

Comment: Yes !, I  was about to write down something similar .

Answer (score 2):

You can play with `onBlur` since it loses focus when another is being cliked.

```js
class DropDown extends React.Component {
  state = {
    isVisible: false
  }
  
  closeMenu = () => {
    this.setState({ isVisible: false })
  }
  
  toggleMenu = () => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({ isVisible: !prevState.isVisible }))
  }
  
  render() {
    const { isVisible } = this.state;
    return (
      <div
        className="dropdown__menu"
        onBlur={this.closeMenu}
        tabIndex={0}
        role="menu"
        onClick={this.toggleMenu}>
        {isVisible ? 'visible' : 'hidden'}
      </div>
    )
  }
}


const App = () => (
  <div>
     <DropDown />
     <DropDown />
  </div>
)
 

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```css
.dropdown__menu {
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since being open is not an information encapsulated in your dropdown's state anymore, I would suggest moving up this information up to your parent component's state.

You should now convert your Dropdowns into stateless functions :

```
const DropdownMenu = ({ menuOpen, count, text, showDropdown }) => ( //props deconstruction
    <div className="dropdown__menu" onClick={showDropdown}>
        {text} 
        {count && <b>{count}</b>} //If you do not want to show anything if a condition is falsy, use the inline if &&
        <div className="dropdown__content" style={{ 'display': menuOpen ? 'block' : 'none' }}> //You can put the ternary condition directly into the JSON
            {this.props.children}
        </div>
    </div>
)
```

You will now have to store which dopdown is opened in your parent component :

```
class Parent extends Component {
    state = {
        openedDropdown = null;
    }
```

And send a callback function to your dropdown :

```
dropdownClicked = openedDropdown => ev => {
    this.setState({ openedDropdown })
}

<DropdownMenu text="New" count={127} disabled showDropdown={this.dropdownClicked('New')}  menuOpen={this.state.openedDropdown === 'New'}/>
<DropdownMenu text="Only show" showDropdown={this.dropdownClicked('Only')}  menuOpen={this.state.openedDropdown === 'Only'}>
    <li>New</li>
    <li>Old</li>
</DropdownMenu>
<DropdownMenu text="Other" showDropdown={this.dropdownClicked('Other')}  menuOpen={this.state.openedDropdown === 'Other'}>
    <li>one</li>
    <li>two</li>
</DropdownMenu>
<DropdownMenu text="Sort by" showDropdown={this.dropdownClicked('Sort')}  menuOpen={this.state.openedDropdown === 'Sort'}>
    <li>Name</li>
    <li>Age</li>
    <li>Value</li>
</DropdownMenu>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use redux for that.
https://redux.js.org/

This solution allows you to manage state for whole app.
It could be used for storing info about opened dropdown, and change it - if necessary.